# Woocommerce - Removing manually part of the URL cause 404 error

Tags: wordpress, seo, woocommerce, http-status-code-404

As mentioned in the Google's "[Search Engine Optimization Starter Guide](http://static.googleusercontent.com/media/www.google.com/en//webmasters/docs/search-engine-optimization-starter-guide.pdf)" (pg 11) a good SEO practice is to give the possibility to users to remove manually part of the URL in the address bar.

In my case:

```
mysite.com/shop/mycategory/myproduct <-- product page with category ok
```

removing now manually part of the URL above:

```
mysite.com/shop/mycategory/ <-- error 404
mysite.com/shop/ <-- works
```

Breadcrumb in the product page look like this:

```
home / shop / mycategory / myproduct
```

clicking on mycategory links to:

```
mysite.com/product-category/mycategory <-- works
```

The problem is that the two URL differs:

```
mysite.com/product-category/mycategory
mysite.com/shop/mycategory/
```

Any clue on how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

From looking at the documentation and other similar posts, some permalinks are not recommended to be adjusted for performance reasons. Your

```
"mysite.com/shop/mycategory/myproduct"
```

url is actually looking at:

```
"mysite.com/shop/product-category/mycategory/myproduct"
```

So it doesn't look like you will be able to shorten it in the way you describe, although you could restore the "product-category" permalink that i assume you have removed? this way the user will be able to shorten the URL without hitting a 404 error.

- http://docs.woothemes.com/document/permalinks/
- [WooCommerce- How to remove product & product-category from urls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21130909/woocommerce-how-to-remove-product-product-category-from-urls)

Comment: what do you mean by "..i assume you have removed?"?  actually I have the default settings for permalinks: product-category + product-tag. I've only selected a custom base with category: /shop/%product_cat%

Comment: My point is that you should be able to deconstruct the URL: mysite.com/shop/product-category/mycategory/myproduct, but you will not be able to deconstruct the URL: "mysite.com/shop/mycategory/myproduct"

Comment: sorry but I cannot deconstruct even mysite.com/shop/product-category/mycategory/myproduct In fact, mysite.com/shop/product-category/mycategory <-- 404mysite.com/shop/product-category/ <-- 404

Comment: But you can mysite.com/product-category/mycategory - You can remove the shop permalink to achieve this.

Comment: I can't remove the shop base. If I do that, the "/product" base is used by default. The only way, at the moment, is to remove the category, keeping only the shop base "/shop". By this way, I have mysite.com/shop/myproduct and can deconstruct the URL with no problem. WC has a very strange way to handle this..